# android camera change orientation

Tags: android, camera, orientation, surface

I make a custom camera on android and faced with the orientation problem.
Activity with surfaceview is portrait orientation, because of this not work onConfigurationChanged listener, but I whant it. 
I want to save picture from camera always in normal orientation,but the images are saved with different orientations depending on how the orientation of the photo was taken.

code:

```
         public void onClickPicture(View view) {
              camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                       try { 
                          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photoFile);
                          fos.write(data);
                          fos.close();
                          Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                          ExifInterface ei;
                              ei = new ExifInterface(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                              int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                              switch (orientation) {
                                  case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                                  //ALAWAYS THIS CASE
                                  break;
                                  case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                                      bm = rotateImage(bm, 90);
                                  break;
                                  case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                                      bm = rotateImage(bm, 180);
                                  break;
                                  case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                      bm = rotateImage(bm, 270);
                                  break;
                               }
                           } catch (Exception e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 });
           }
```

Comment: If you post your custom camera code, people will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) and create an instance of it in your activity. After that you invoke `enable` method of this instance.
Whenever the orientation of your device changes, the method [OrientationEventListener#onOrientationChanged(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html#onOrientationChanged(int)) will be called. In this method you can calculate the new rotation to be set in camera's parameters via the [Camera.Parameters#setRotation(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int)) method.